# What is the path environment variable?

Tags: command-line, environment-variables, path

I just started with using the (Windows) command line tool for working with npm. And I end up quite often on StackOverflow when I'm stuck with some error and the solution is often to add [something] to the Path Environment variable.

But what exactly *is* the path environment variable? How do I add variables to it? Are these variables added permanently? How can I read/print this Path Environment variable. I suppose it's some kind of an array.

**Basicly can you give me a heads up about what the PATH environment variable *is*, what it *does*, *why* it exists and how to *(ab)use* it.**